# Display table from code behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a function in my program that prints a string consisting of a table to the page.

```
getWhileLoopData(){          
        string htmlStr = "";
        SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);     
        SqlCommand thisCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();       
        thisCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * from events";      
        thisConnection.Open();      
        SqlDataReader reader = thisCommand.ExecuteReader();      
        while (reader.Read()){      
            int room_id = reader.GetInt32(0);
            string title = reader.GetString(1);                
            htmlStr += "<tr><td>" + title + "</td></tr>";                        
        }      
        thisConnection.Close();      
        return htmlStr;
}
```

In the .aspx page I call it by `<%=getWhileLoopData()%>` It works. 
But the problem is when I open the page in the `page_load(object sender, EventArgs e)` function I have something similar, it appends table values to a string.

How do I make the string from the page_load() function print to the screen?

Comment: It's not very clear what your result is... can you show the output? and specify from there what you would like it to say instead?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by `appends table values to a string`? That's what your code is telling it to do. Are you asking for a way to populate an HTML table from your `reader` without manually building the string?

Comment: Also, building HTML by concatenating strings in this way is a very inefficient, difficult-to-maintain approach. This isn't PHP.

Comment: So what the code above print are the two columns in the database as a table.

Comment: the load_page() has almost similar code as this but the query is different.

Comment: What is happening that is different than what you want to happen? You should really be binding your reader to a GridView or similar control to generate the HTML. Can you can always use `Response.Write(htmlStr);`, but this is a very sloppy solution to generating HTML dynamically.

Comment: I was doing that at first, but someone suggested this way. The problem I was having with the GridView was how to use two different datasources.

Comment: Why would you have two different data sources?

Comment: They are two different queries.

Answer (score 1):

If you have specific HTML you want to put on the page based on some data, a better way would be to use one of the existing .net controls, e.g. a Repeater linked to a DataSource.  A DataSource can be a database, or a List (basically anything that implements IEnumerable).

Optionally, you could create your own control by inheriting from WebControl and override the Render Event to render your HTML.

If you go the custom control route, you would just do something like

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="XYZ" NameSpace="XYZ.MyControlsNameSpace" Assembly="MyControlsAssembly" %>
```

Then to use it,

```
<XYZ:MyNewCustomControl runat="server" SomeProperty="SomeValue" ... />
```

When the aspx engine encounters XYZ:MyNewCustomControl it will insert the control into the page at that point and run it through the page event life cycle, causing it to be rendered, causing it's Render Event to fire, where all of it's HTML will be injected into the page.

Comment: +1 for using an off-the-shelf control. Based on the question, implementing a custom control may be a little too advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I think is better you get a div as runat server then after call your function set innerhtml propertry with your html code.

```
<div id="test" runat="server></div>
```

in codebehinde

```
test.innerhtml="<p>Hi</p>"
```